# Deleted the .ssh folder from aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have mistakenly deleted the .ssh folder from my aws instance and now I am unable to ssh into it. The issue is that node is in my prod environment and I dont want to restart it. I have found the following solution -

[Amazon AWS EC2 Deleted Key Locked out of Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160673/amazon-aws-ec2-deleted-key-locked-out-of-root)

But it suggests that I need to attach my disk to another instance which will cause the node to shutdown and still the solution is not assured. Is there any solution which is provided at aws console which I can utilise. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you delete the .ssh folder from the AWS created user (i.e. "ubuntu" or "ec2-user")?  Or from a personalized account made after logging in the first time?

Comment: from the aws created user "ubuntu".

Comment: Then sorry, you're out of luck.  On the bright side, you've learned a lesson.  Create a separate user.  I've learned the hard way a few times :)

Answer (score 9):

This is an old issue, but in case someone wonders in here with this problem, there is a quick and relatively painless fix that can be done today by following this procedure from [AWS Knowledge Base](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/user-data-replace-key-pair-ec2/).

Basic details are as follows:

1. Generate a Private Key (I'm on Mac bash shell, so will use .pem format)
2. Run `ssh-keygen -yf <KEY-FILE>.pem` to get Public Key
3. Stop the instance.
4. Actions -> Instance Settings -> View/Change User Data

   ```yaml
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
   MIME-Version: 1.0

   --//
   Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

   #cloud-config
   cloud_final_modules:
   - [users-groups, once]
   users:
     - name: USERNAME-REPLACE
       ssh-authorized-keys: 
       - PUBLIC-KEY-PAIR-REPLACE
   ```

   > Replace **USERNAME-REPLACE** with instance username (e.g.: ubuntu, ec2-user, etc.)
   >
   > Replace **PUBLIC-KEY-PAIR-REPLACE** with what you printed in step 2, including `ssh-rsa` part.
5. Save
6. Start the instance
7. Verify SSH works
8. Stop the instance
9. Remove User Data you entered
10. Start the instance

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution that doesn't involve working with the EBS volume detached from the instance.

Perhaps you could launch a copy of this instance, fix it, and then move the  elastic IP address to the fixed instance with minimal down time?

Comment: It is not an ebs backed instance. So it can only be restarted or terminated.

Comment: Then you are out of luck

Comment: These days it is not recommended to use an instance-stored back instance unless there is a very specific need. Using EBS-backed instances have many benefits (stop/start, snapshots, reattaching, etc).